# Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'true'

Tags: typescript

Here is the code i have:

```
type UnlockLevel = {
  unlocked: false;
  unlockLevel: number;
} | {
  unlocked: true;
  unlockLevel: undefined;
}

function getUnlockData(level: number, unlockLevel: number): UnlockLevel {
  const unlocked = level >= unlockLevel;
  
  return {
    unlocked,
    unlockLevel: unlocked ? undefined : unlockLevel,
  }
}
```

I receive the following error:
`Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'true'.`

It can be fixed with the ugly:

```
if (unlocked) {
  return { unlocked: true, unlockLevel };
} else {
  return { unlocked: false, unlockLevel: undefined }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this and tell the compiler that the tuple is valid or to adjust the type to allow the first implementation without loosing the constraint?

I researched this issue but didn't find any helpful resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting issue.
I've played around with this a bit and at this point I believe it's a TS limitation.
I feel like it's just not able to infer the proper type the way you want it to.

With that said, IMO your proposed solution is not "ugly" but actually rather more explicit, which I personally feel is better most of the times and compliments the choice of using TS to begin with.

The one small thing I would change in your provided code is remove the `unlocked: true` / `unlocked: false`, as that can be automatically assigned instead.

So something like:

```
function getUnlockData(level: number, unlockLevel: number): UnlockLevel {
  const unlocked = level >= unlockLevel;
  
  if (unlocked) {
    return { unlocked, unlockLevel: undefined }
  } else {
    return { unlocked, unlockLevel }
  }
}
```

Makes it a bit cleaner.

Another thing to consider is why the "unlockLevel" needs to be `undefined` at all.
Which raises the greater question of the purpose of this function and interface.

If I understand the context correctly, then a simple `isUnlocked` type function that returns `boolean` would fill the same purpose.
Especially as we already provide the level & unlock level that serve to determine whether or not it's unlocked.

Comment: Thanks for your investigation, i researched little further and also came to the conclusion that it seems to be a limitation of TS. I went with this approach now even tho i think a single return would have been better to fit a broader amount of cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's how the compiler works. If you don't like that option using type guards you can try something different like

```js
function choiceHelper<
  const Source extends boolean,
  const Choice1,
  const Choice2,
>(source: Source, choice1: Choice1, choice2: Choice2) {
  return (source ? choice1 : choice2) as [Source] extends [
    true,
  ]
    ? Choice1
    : Choice2;
}

type UnlockLevel = {
  unlocked: false;
  unlockLevel: number;
} | {
  unlocked: true;
  unlockLevel: undefined;
}

function getUnlockData(level: number, unlockLevel: number): UnlockLevel {
  const unlocked = level >= unlockLevel;

  return {
    unlocked: choiceHelper(unlocked, true, false),
    unlockLevel: choiceHelper(unlocked, undefined, unlockLevel),
  }
}
```

Also there is shorter version of type guard than can be achieved by applying 2 fixes.

1. making it use ternary instead of `if`
2. not specify `unlocked: true` and `unlocked: false` manually because `unlocked` will be inferred automatically inside `if` branch's scope:

```js
type UnlockLevel = {
  unlocked: false;
  unlockLevel: number;
} | {
  unlocked: true;
  unlockLevel: undefined;
}

function getUnlockData(level: number, unlockLevel: number): UnlockLevel {
  const unlocked = level >= unlockLevel;

  return unlocked
    ? { unlocked, unlockLevel: undefined }
    : { unlocked, unlockLevel };
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to set type boolean in type UnlockLevel.
unlocked: boolean

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).